# Weighted averaging a list

Tags: python, list, average

Thanks for your responses. Yes, I was looking for the weighted average.

```
rate = [14.424, 14.421, 14.417, 14.413, 14.41]

amount = [3058.0, 8826.0, 56705.0, 30657.0, 12984.0]
```

I want the weighted average of the top list based on each item of the bottom list.

So, if the first bottom-list item is small (such as 3,058 compared to the total 112,230), then the first top-list item should have less of an effect on the top-list average.

Here is some of what I have tried. It gives me an answer that looks right, but I am not sure if it follows what I am looking for.

```
for g in range(len(rate)):
    rate[g] = rate[g] * (amount[g] / sum(amount))
rate = sum(rate)
```

EDIT:
After comparing other responses with my code, I decided to use the zip code to keep it as short as possible.

Comment: Do you mean [weighted average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean)

Comment: @Pyson None of these lists seem to have a sum of 100 percent, so I'm not sure about that.

Comment: If you are looking for a weighted average as @Pyson mentioned, a good idea is to normalise the second vector, and apply the w.a algorithm

Comment: I knew weighted average, I just had a brain fart. Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
for g in range(len(rate)):
   rate[g] = rate[g] * amount[g] / sum(amount)
rate = sum(rate)
```

is the same as:

```
sum(rate[g] * amount[g] / sum(amount) for g in range(len(rate)))
```

which is the same as:

```
sum(rate[g] * amount[g] for g in range(len(rate))) / sum(amount)
```

which is the same as:

> sum(x * y for x, y in zip(rate, amount)) / sum(amount)

Result:

```
14.415602815646439
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. The one highlighted in yellow gave me a syntax error though.

Comment: I tried it again, it worked this time. I probably copied something extra on the page accidentally. I will use your yellow-highlighted code. Thanks!

Comment: I would highly discourage this answer in favor of the other proposed `np.average`: numpy belongs de facto to the standard library. And then, if we already have an implementation, let's not reinvent the wheel (not even talking about the speed)

Answer (score 60):

You could use `numpy.average` to calculate weighted average.

```
In [13]: import numpy as np

In [14]: rate = [14.424, 14.421, 14.417, 14.413, 14.41]

In [15]: amount = [3058.0, 8826.0, 56705.0, 30657.0, 12984.0]

In [17]: weighted_avg = np.average(rate, weights=amount)

In [19]: weighted_avg
Out[19]: 14.415602815646439
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to use included 2.7.9 libraries.

Comment: Numpy is _de facto_ standard library

Comment: *de facto* is subjective. Numpy is **not** standard library.

Answer (score 9):

This looks like a weighted average.

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
weights = [2, 8, 50, 30, 10]

s = 0
for x, y in zip(values, weights):
    s += x * y

average = s / sum(weights)
print(average) # 3.38
```

This outputs `3.38`, which indeed tends more toward the values with the highest weights.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use python `zip` function

```
zip([iterable, ...])
```

This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence. When there are multiple arguments which are all of the same length, zip() is similar to map() with an initial argument of None. With a single sequence argument, it returns a list of 1-tuples. With no arguments, it returns an empty list.

```
weights = [14.424, 14.421, 14.417, 14.413, 14.41]
values = [3058.0, 8826.0, 56705.0, 30657.0, 12984.0]
weighted_average = sum(weight * value for weight, value in zip(weights, values)) / sum(weights)
```

Comment: You have the weights and values swapped. I want the 14.000 values to be weighted based on thousand values.

Answer (score 0):

As a documented and tested function:

```
def weighted_average(values, weights=None):
    """
    Returns the weighted average of `values` with weights `weights`
    Returns the simple aritmhmetic average if `weights` is None.
    >>> weighted_average([3, 9], [1, 2])
    7.0
    >>> 7 == (3*1 + 9*2) / (1 + 2)
    True
    """
    if weights == None:
        weights = [1 for _ in range(len(values))]
    normalization = 0
    val = 0
    for value, weight in zip(values, weights):
        val += value * weight
        normalization += weight
    return val / normalization
```

For completeness another version where the values and weights are stored in tuples:

```
def weighted_average(values_and_weights):
    """
    The input is expected in the form:
        [(value_1, weight_1), (value_2, weight_2), ...(value_n, weight_n)]
    >>> weighted_average([(3,1), (9,2)])
    7.0
    >>> 7 == (3*1 + 9*2) / (1 + 2)
    True

    """
    normalization = 0
    val = 0
    for value, weight in values_and_weights:
        val += value * weight
        normalization += weight
    return val / normalization
```